# VS2022 with CMake and Ubuntu on WSL2 can't find directories

Tags: cmake, wsl-2, visual-studio-2022

I have a question regarding VS2022 and Ubuntu on WSL2:
I have a big project to was created for windows environment and now I am working on having it cross platform for Linux also. I decided to use Ubuntu and WSL2 for ease of use and with VS2022 along CMake so I can work with just one code base.

My folder structure is as following:

```
-ProjectA
-LibProjectA
-LibProjectB
-ProjectB
-ProjectC
```

Projects A,B and C are dependent on LibProjectA and LibProjectB.

When using the CMake and VS2022, it uses rsync to copy the files to the Ubuntu machine but it changes the folder structure to this:

```
-ProjectA
  |-LibProjectA
  |-LibProjectB
-ProjectB
  |-LibProjectA
  |-LibProjectB
-ProjectC
  |-LibProjectA
  |-LibProjectB
```

In the CMake of ProjectA, I have:

```
add_subdirectory(../LibProjectA ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/LibProjectA)
add_subdirectory(../LibProjectB ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/LibProjectB)
```

And the same for ProjectB and ProjectC.

Because of this, the relatives paths are changed and it cannot find the files.
Did anyone encountered this or knows how to solve this?

I am also using an automated tool I found called "cmake-converter" because the projects includes alot more of libs and directories.

I googled and I can't seem to find anyone who had this issue. I Also tried to create top level CMake that will have all the directories as sub level and on the same level, but still when rsync is being performed it creates the wrong directories structure.

Comment: Why copy the files with rsync? You should be able to access the windows file system via `/mnt/<windows drive letter>/<path>`. If the cmake project is written well and you don't write anything to the source directory, you can just point cmake at the path to the code on windows. If you've got a git repo with symlinks or files relying on certain rights, this won't work properly, but if you rely on this, it may be an indication that something is wrong with the cmake project.

Comment: The rsync way, its because of VS2022, it does it by itself. When you work cross platform it requires CMake and it copies the files to the linux machine and compiles them.